# AudioContext not playing any sound on iPadOS

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I'm developing a simple music player library ([Euterpe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@euterpe.js/euterpe)) and I've run into an issue where playback is broken on Apple devices.

Trying out this minimal example:

```js
const ctx = new AudioContext()
const audio_el = document.createElement("audio")
audio_el.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
document.body.appendChild(audio_el)
const track = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio_el)
track.connect(ctx.destination)

const button = document.createElement("button")
button.innerHTML = "demo_play"
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  audio_el.src = "https://ia600604.us.archive.org/20/items/78_gomen-nasai-forgive-me_columbia-tokyo-orchestra-richard-bowers-b.-meyers-r.-hatto_gbia0009754a/Gomen-Nasai%20%28Forgive%20Me%29%20-%20Columbia%20Tokyo%20Orchestra.mp3"
  ctx.resume()
  audio_el.play()
})
document.body.appendChild(button)
```

iPad pretends audio is playing, but the audio time isn't progressing, no sound is coming out and no errors get thrown during this process.

But on any other browser core and any platform it works fine. Firefox, chromium etc.

I found multiple webkit bug reports around this, but I don't know if this issue still persists as all of them have been marked solved.
Examples:

- WebAudio muted when... :https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=251532
- decodeAudioData regression in Safari 15 ... https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231872
- https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/1513

Relevant code snippets for euterpe (web demo [here](https://github.com/euterpe-js/euterpe-source/tree/master/packages/euterpe-web-test) ):

```js
const euterpe = new EuterpeBuilder(document.querySelector("#audio")!, db)
    .build()
// when user clicks play on a song from library
function library_play(e: MouseEvent) {
    const b = e.currentTarget as HTMLButtonElement
    euterpe.try_specific_song_async(parseInt(b.dataset["id"]!)).then(
        () => document.querySelector("#text-playing")!.innerHTML = euterpe.format_current_song(),
        (e) => alert(e)
    )
}
```

Functions used:

```js
try_specific_song_async(new_song_id: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const new_song = this.db.songs.find((song) => song.id! == new_song_id)
    if (!new_song) reject(new Error(`No song with id "${new_song_id}" found`))
    else {
      this.try_new_song_async(new_song.url.toString()).then(
        () => {
          this.try_play_async().then((s) => {
            if (this.current_song) this.played_history.push(this.current_song)
            this.current_song = new_song
            this.current_song_id = new_song.id!
            resolve(s)
          }, (e) => reject(e))
        },
        (e) => reject(e)
      )
    }
  })
}
//...
try_new_song_async(path: string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.audio_element.src = this.current_song_path = path
    //Found out today about this. Such a nice new way to mass remove event listeners!
    const controller = new AbortController();

    this.audio_element.addEventListener("canplay", function canplay_listener(s) {
      controller.abort()
      resolve(s)
    }, { signal: controller.signal })

    this.audio_element.addEventListener("error", function error_listener(e) {
      controller.abort()
      reject(e)
    }, { signal: controller.signal })

    this.audio_element.addEventListener("stalled", function stalled_listener(e) {
      controller.abort()
      reject(e)
    }, { signal: controller.signal })

    //once aborted, try to set current_song_duration
    controller.signal.addEventListener("abort", () => {
      this.current_song_duration = this.audio_element.duration
    })

    this.is_playing = false
  })
}
//...
try_play_async() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (this.is_playing) resolve(Error("Already playing"))
    if (this.track.context.state !== "running") {
      this.audio_context.resume().then(() => {
        this.audio_element.play().then((s) => {
          this.is_playing = true
          resolve(s)
        }, (r) => {
          this.is_playing = false
          reject(r)
        })
      }, (e) =>
        reject(new Error("Context closed or suspended" + JSON.stringify(e))))
    } else {
      this.audio_element.play().then((s) => {
        this.is_playing = true
        resolve(s)
      }, (r) => {
        this.is_playing = false
        reject(r)
      })
    }
  })
}
```

And audioContext is built like this:

```js
class EuterpeBuilder {
  constructor(private audio_element: HTMLAudioElement, db){
    const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
    this.#audio_context = new AudioContext()
    this.#track = this.#audio_context.createMediaElementSource(audio_element)
    this.#gain = this.#audio_context.createGain()
  }
//...
  build() {
    if (!this.#is_gain_connected) {
      !this.#prev_node ? this.#track.connect(this.#gain) : this.#prev_node.connect(this.#gain)
      this.#prev_node = this.#gain
    }
    this.#prev_node.connect(this.#audio_context.destination)
    this.audio_element.preload = "metadata"
    return new Euterpe(this.db, this.#audio_context, this.audio_element, this.#track, this.#gain, this.#volume)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue by running the minimal example on my iPad but was unable to reproduce it. The audio played as expected. For reference, some environment details: iPad Pro 11" 3rd Gen, iPadOS v16.6. Can you confirm you experience the issue with the minimal example in your question? Also, do you experience this on other Apple devices or just iPad?

Comment: @Wing 
My colleague is apparently running iOS & iPadOS 17 betas on their iPhone 13 Pro Max and iPad Air 2020, respectively. We have currently not been able to test i(Pad)OS devices on stable release channels.
Might this be related to some safari updates on iOS 17? Might explain why we haven’t been able to find other reports.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have spare devices to install iOS betas. I did attempt reproducing on iOS 17 via a simulator but was unable to reproduce. The audio played as expected. When you say "but on any other browser core and any platform it works fine. Firefox, chromium etc" are you testing on Firefox/Chrome/etc on iOS or are you testing Firefox/Chrome/etc on Mac / other non-mobile OS?

Comment: After more testing - It's a webkit / Safari issue. That demo works on Safari, and so does our web-test-demo for our library, just in our actual app it seems to break. https://github.com/euterpe-js/euterpe-source/tree/master/packages/euterpe-web-test

Comment: Do you have instructions for reproduction?

Comment: https://github.com/nuphory/hypertrance/blob/v3/src/routes/Sample.svelte
This is the exact code that doesn't work, though I feel like now it's more of an issue on my end than audioContext given this exact same lib works fine on another site.

Comment: i can reproduce the problem. same code worked on ios 16. stopped working on ios 17 beta rc. The createMediaElementSource line breaks the code. Without that the audio is playable. The issue seems to be reported already: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=260412